# Inspecting a container using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubectl

Is there a way to inspect a container running in pod directly from the kubernetes command line (using kubectl) to see some details such as running in priveleged mode for instance.
something like:

```
kubectl inspect -c <containerName>
```

The only way I found is to ssh to the node hosting the pod and perform a `docker inspect <containerID>` but this is kind of tedious.

My kubernetes version

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:55:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0+coreos.0", GitCommit:"6bb2e725fc2876cd94b3900fc57a1c98ca87a08b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-04-02T16:49:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: `kubectl describe`?

Answer (score 9):

Check `kubectl describe pods/<pod_name>`

If it is not enough for you, you can go for JSON and filter it with `jq`

`kubectl get <pod_name> -ojson | jq '.spec.containers[] | .securityContext'`

Also, check [kubectl Cheat Sheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/)

Comment: Requires `kubectl get *pod* <pod_name> ...`, at least now. +1 for the `jq` example.

Answer (score 2):

I a similar problem, that I had a pod with status Evicted and needed to inspect it (on kubectl is describe). So i used:

```
kubectl describe pod <pod-name>
```

So I could see what I was looking for:

```
...
Status:         Failed
Reason:         Evicted
Message:        Pod The node had condition: [DiskPressure]. 
...
```

So searching i found a very nice article talking about [12 Critical Kubernetes Health Conditions You Need to Monitor and Why](https://www.circonus.com/2020/12/12-critical-kubernetes-health-conditions-you-need-to-monitor-and-why/).

Still on solving, but this log may help others.

Answer (score 1):

You have below kubectl commands to know details of a pod

```
kubectl describe <pod_name> -n <namespacename>
kubectl get <pod_name>  -n <namespacename> -o yaml # output in yaml format  
kubectl get <pod_name> -n <namespacename> -o json # output in json format
```

If you want to know which containers are running in privileged mode from an audit point of view then I suggest to look at project [Falco](https://falco.org) which has a mechanism to write policies and trigger alert when a container is violating a policy. The policy could be *no container can run in privileged mode*.

Comment: kubectl describe mypod -c mycontainer does not work for me. -> Error : Unknown shorthand flag : 'c' in -c. I update my question with my k8s version.

Comment: My bad..describe does not take container as parameter